# If I could go back in time, a time when I wasn't born/hadn't been born/didn't exist yet, I would

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, conditionals, tense-agreement

Which would be correct here and why?

> If I could go back in time, a time when **I wasn't born/hadn't been
> born/didn't exist** yet, I would...

Comment: Obligatory [Douglas Adams reference](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~param/quotes/guide.html). (Note to learners: this is fictional satire, not real grammar, but it's a very fun read.)

Comment: I think you need '**to** a time'. _If I could go back in time, to a time before I was born, I would..._ Or just, _If I could go back to a time before I was born, I would..._ I prefer the first. The repetition of the word 'time' - **with** the comma - seems to make the sense clearer.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian thank you! Does it mean that saying 'to a time when I wasn't born/hadn't been born/didn't exist yet' is wrong and we need to say 'to a time before I was born'?

Comment: @i_yre_b@ Asked by a child "Do you remember VE Day/the Civil War/the last ice age?" most people (in the UK) would probably say, "No. That was before I was born/long before I was born/long, _long_ before I was born." "Before I was born" is colloquial and grammatically correct. "to a time when I wasn't born", though the grammar's OK, sounds awkward. You weren't born yesterday, so yesterday was **also** a time when you weren't born. "To a time when I hadn't been born" is grammatically sound but it's overstating an easy thought: "To a time before I was born" is more natural. ...

Comment: @i_yre_b:  "To a time when I didn't exist yet" is grammatically poor. "To a time when I didn't yet exist" is grammatically better. Again, it's an overstatement of an easy thought. That's the best I can do without knowing the context.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian thank you! Your explanations are very useful!

Answer (score 1):

**A time when I hadn't been born** and **A time when I wasn't alive** are both correct.

**A time when I wasn't born** is incorrect. Obviously the labor and birthing process is not instantaneous, but compared to the length of someone's life it is nearly so, and in any case it is not a *continuous state of being* the way "being alive" is.

Comment: Thank you, Randomhead! How about 'didn't exist'? 'Wasn't alive' sounds as if I was dead. :)